# How to simulate the success of an RF packet transfer knowing the packet size and BER

Tags: simulation

I'm trying to simulate a data protocol running over a 5 Mbps RF link.  The datasheet for the RF chip gives a logarithmic BER vs SNR plot (BER := bit error rate; SNR := signal to noise ratio), but to simplify I am choosing to fix the BER to the same value that many of the RF characteristics are measured: BER = 10^-4.

How do I determine the instantaneous success of a packet transfer of size N bits (N := { 36000, 18000, 9000, 4500})?

I'm not looking for the probability of success (but that may be needed as an interim calculation).  I need to be able to make a boolean decision about each packet as the simulation time ticks by.  I also have a random number generator available as input and can keep a packet transfer history if necessary.  I'm using the [SimPy](http://simpy.sourceforge.net/) package for even simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question.  You just want to know immediately if a packet has a bit error?  If not, could you clarify your question to more clearly state what you want to find?

BER is essentially the probability of a bit error.  1 in 10,000 bits has an error.  So, if you do (1-BER)^N you'll get the probability that packet succeeded.  Then, for your simulation to determine if any given packet was successful get a number between 0 and 1 from your PRNG.  If it's less than your (1-BER)^N, that packet was successful.  Otherwise that packet contained a bit error.

Comment: Yes, the presence of a bit error is what I want to find.  I arrived at a similar solution as you, but I didn't trust my decade-old one-semester grasp of statistics.  I thought there might be more to it that this.

Comment: shouldn't it be 1-(1-BER)^N ? as given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_error_rate#Packet_error_ratio